# Как найти скрытые div без поиска в дочерних элементах

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно из определенного списка div взять только те, которые помечены как скрытые то есть имеют такой маркер `style = "display:none;`. В моем коде, он получается ищет скрытые в том числе и дочерние элементы, а мне нужно, чтобы из списка в n элементов, он указал какие именно из этих n есть скрытые.

Мой код:

```
var blocks = $('#first, #second, #formFirst, #commentsForm, #secondLevelForm, #secondLevelFormContainer, #secondResultLevelData, .resultBtn');
var hide = blocks.find('div', ':hidden');
```

но в переменной `hide` оказывается еще много всяких дивов, но мне нужны лишь те , что из списка

Comment: используй [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 2):

Неудивительно, так как ты используешь селектор `:hidden`. Давай прочитаем, что про него написано [в документации](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/):

> They have a CSS display value of none.
>   They are form elements with type="hidden".
>   Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
>   An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

То есть, если элемент c нулевой высотой и шириной, а это может быть потому, что он просто пустой, или же потому, что он еще не успел отрисоваться, будет отвечать этому селектору.

Плюс, ты неверно используешь `find()`, передавая в него два параметра сразу, в итоге он найдет тебе и все элементы c `:hidden`, и все `div`, насколько я понимаю, но тут нужно смотреть код самого JQuery. Тогда как надо искать одним запросом, скажем так, делая `find("div:hidden")`.

Но и это будет неверно, так как в итоге он тебе выдаст действительно все вложенные элементы, и нужно будет это как-то фильтровать. Поэтому проще использовать такой код, как ниже - сначала отфильтровать все элементы в массиве через `filter("div:hidden")`, а после просто перебрать его через `$.each()`.

Обрати внимание, у нас скрыты и все вложенные элементы в те, которые ты включаешь в `blocks`, и один из собственно членов данного массива. В итоге сообщение будет содержать только его.

```js
$("body").ready(function() {
  var blocks = $("#level1_1, #level1_2").filter("div:hidden");
  $.each(blocks, function() {
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
#level2_1,
#level2_2,
#level2_3,
#level2_4 {
  display: none
}
#level1_1 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="level1_1">
    <div id="level2_1">

    </div>
    <div id="level2_2">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="level1_2">
    <div id="level2_3">

    </div>
    <div id="level2_4">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```